# How to add custom headers to content::JSON in Rocket?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

Say I have this route handler in [`rocket`](https://crates.io/crates/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1) (v. 0.5.0-rc.1):

```rust
#[get("/route")]
pub async fn my_route() -> content::Json<String> {
    let json =
        rocket::serde::json::serde_json::to_string(&my_data).unwrap();
    content::Json(json)
}
```

how could I add another header (apart from `content-type: application/json`) to the response?

I thought of something like this, but it does not work:

```rust
#[get("/route")]
pub async fn my_route() -> content::Json<String> {
    let json =
        rocket::serde::json::serde_json::to_string(&my_data).unwrap();
    let mut content = content::Json(json);
    content.set_raw_header("Cache-Control", "max-age=120");
    content
}
```

I would be fine with using a raw `rocket::Response` and setting the `content-type: application/json` header myself, but I was unable to figure out how to set the body from a variable length string without running into lifetime issues.

Comment: In the documentation (https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/responses/) they say to use `use rocket::response::content; ... fn json() -> content::Json<&'static str>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a raw response with the JSON string like so:

```
let json =
    rocket::serde::json::serde_json::to_string(&[1, 2, 3]).unwrap();
let response = Response::build()
    .header(ContentType::JSON)
    .raw_header("Cache-Control", "max-age=120")
    .sized_body(json.len(), Cursor::new(json))
    .finalize();
```

Comment: This lead my on the right path. I had to define a struct, implement the `Responder` trait for it and then build the response in the `respond_to(self, _request: &'r rocket::Request<'_>) -> rocket::response::Result<'static> {` function.